# Change Forms Authentication in Feature Delegations in IIS using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, forms-authentication, powershell-4.0

I want to change Forms Authentication [Feature Delegation] to "Read Only" in Server level using powershell. I could find alternatives for windows and anonymous authentication but couldn't do for Forms. Is there a way to do so?

I have tried this command:

```
Set-WebConfiguration /system.WebServer/Security/Authentication/formsAuthentication -metadata overrideMode -value Allow -PSPath IIS:/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested and researched, found the reason, and I don't think it's possible to change **FormsAuthentication** in **Feature Delegations** via powershell.

Just like what you tried, I used this code to successfully change windowsAuthentication and basicAuthentication to read/only or read/write.

```
$property = @{
    Filter   = "/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication"
    Force    = $true
    PSPath   = "IIS:/"
    Value    = "Allow"
    Metadata = "overrideMode"
}
Set-WebConfiguration @property
```

When I try the code below, I get an error.

```
$property = @{
    Filter   = "/system.webServer/security/authentication/formsAuthentication"
    Force    = $true
    PSPath   = "IIS:/"
    Value    = "Allow"
    Metadata = "overrideMode"
}
Set-WebConfiguration @property
```

**WARNING: Target configuration object '/system.WebServer/Security/Authentication/formsAuthentication is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'.**

Then I tried looking for the answer in **configuration editor**. There is no FormsAuthentication here. I tried adding FormsAuthentication (stupid behavior) to Security in applicationHost.config, it didn't work. By consulting the official documentation, I found an explanation that FormsAuthentication is an ASP.NET configuration. Feature Delegations like WindowsAuthentication and bisic are IIS features.

So, it may be better to manually change Forms Authentication to read/only in IIS directly. If there has better idea, welcome to discuss。